# YYYY to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, datetime

In date section, i have year "yyyy" in the numeric format, how to convert that into mm/dd/yyyy (may be 12/31/ as prefix before yyyy). Any help would certainly appreciable

Comment: Which type of SQL? Oracle? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use string to date conversion:-

```
TO_DATE('12/31/year','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Just concatenate your default date month (12/31) with Year and use TO_DATE function.

In Oracle you can concatenate like `string_date = '12/31' || '/' || year` 
Then you can convert this to date as `TO_DATE(string_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )`

considering yyyy is a variable holding year value.

Comment: at least use the OP value `year` to show how  to do it